# Configure matching settings for locate-source for helm-mini

Tags: helm, helm-sources

How can I configure `helm-source-locate` (for `helm-mini`) such that it matches like the following:

Type `some tex` it should match `some_file.tex` as well as `b_some_other_file.tex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to change the helm-locate command:

```
(setq helm-locate-command "locate %s -e -A --regex %s")
```

(See: https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/940)

Since I want spaces and regex, it is not a fuzzy search what I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy matching (enabled for some commands but disabled by default) should do the trick:

```el
(setq helm-locate-fuzzy-match t)
(setq helm-mode-fuzzy-match t)
```

and/or:

```el
(setq helm-completion-in-region-fuzzy-match t)
```